# BASH: replacing PERL with SED for in-place substitution

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed

Would like to replace this statement with perl:

```
perl -pe "s|(?<=://).+?(?=/)|$2:80|"
```

with

```
sed -e "s|<regex>|$2:80|"
```

Since sed has a much less powerful regex engine (for example it does not support look-arounds) the task boils down to writing a sed compatible regex to match only a domain name in a fully qualitied URL. Examples:

```
http://php2-mindaugasb.c9.io/Testing/JS/displayName.js
http://php2-mindaugasb.c9.io?a=Testing.js
http://www.google.com?a=Testing.js
```

Should become:

```
http://$2:80/Testing/JS/displayName.js
http://$2:80?a=Testing.js
http://$2:80?a=Testing.js
```

A solution like this  would be ok:

```
sed -e "s|<regex>|http://$2:80|"
```

Thanks :)

Comment: but your expected output didn't contain 80.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below sed command.

```
$ sed "s~//[^/?]\+\([?/]\)~//\$2:80\1~g" file
http://$2:80/Testing/JS/displayName.js
http://$2:80?a=Testing.js
http://$2:80?a=Testing.js
```

You must need to escape the `$` at the replacement part.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I did not manage to think about negated character classes somehow :)

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's|http://[^/?]*|http://$2:80|' file
```

Output:

```
http://$2:80/Testing/JS/displayName.js
http://$2:80?a=Testing.js
http://$2:80?a=Testing.js
```